# How to use two search domains with pdnsd on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, dns

I have a local network and a VPN connection - both with different domains.

Is there any possibility to use both domains as search domains for DNS-lookup? I already got pdnsd to only lookup the VPN-domains on the VPN DNS server and the local domain names on the local server. Also when looking up `hostname` it resolves to `hostname.domain1.local`, but when trying to lookup names from the second domain with the short hostname the DNS returns an `NXDOMAIN`.

Is there any possibility to let my system try `hostname.domain1.local` and if that is not found `hostname.domain2.local` when looking up `hostname`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add (as sudo) these two lines to your /etc/resolv.conf file, at the very bottom:

```
search hostname.domain1.local
search hostname.domain2.local
```

Careful, the /etc/resolv.conf file is erased and re-written every time you establish a new connection.

Edit: my bad. [The linux manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolver.5.html) states:

> **search**  *Search list for host-name lookup.*
>                 The search list is normally determined from the local domain
>                 name; by default, it contains only the local domain name.
>                 This may be changed by listing the desired domain search path
>                 following the search keyword with spaces or tabs separating
>                 the names.  Resolver queries having fewer than ndots dots
>                 (default is 1) in them will be attempted using each component
>                 of the search path in turn until a match is found.  For
>                 environments with multiple subdomains please read options
>                 ndots:n below to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks and
>                 unnecessary traffic for the root-dns-servers.  Note that this
>                 process may be slow and will generate a lot of network traffic
>                 if the servers for the listed domains are not local, and that
>                 queries will time out if no server is available for one of the
>                 domains.

```
          The search list is currently limited to six domains with a
          total of 256 characters.
```

So this should have been:

```
search hostname.domain1.local  hostname.domain2.local
```

Comment: I tried this but it just won't work. The first search domain works just fine, but when the first domain doesn't resolve `hostname.domain1.local` it still returns the NX instead of the record for `hostname.domain2.local`